# Call VBA of Word template from .NET at server side using Sharepoint Server?

Tags: asp.net, office, vba

Can i call a VBA macro of a Word document, using .NET and Sharepoint Server? I mean, in a .NET client environment i can do this:

```
oW = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oW.Documents.Add("template.dotm")
oW.Application.Run("macroVBA")
```

Is there an equivalent to this code using Word Automation Services? They sell themselves this way:

> In simplest terms, Word Automation Services takes the "Save As…"
>   functionality of the Word client application and replicates it for the
>   server.

I know that Automation is discouraged at server side, but when i saw that slogan i was wondering if there was some kind of support for VBA legacy code